# Threading Facebook API Access Token

Tags: python, python-2.7, facebook-graph-api, access-token, python-multithreading

I am new to threading. In fact, I have never learn it before.

I am trying to use threading to retrieve access token from Facebook so that my access token will be able to extend automatically, without me have to manually retrieve it every one hour.

What I am trying to do:
[image]

So I saw some codes related to Thread in the Stackoverflow, and try it out. Eventually, it works but how do I only collect Facebook access token? Can anyone help me out please?

```
import Queue
import threading
import urllib2

# called by each thread
def get_url(q, url):
q.put(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

theurls = ["My facebook developer gpaph api explorer URL"]

q = Queue.Queue()

for u in theurls:
t = threading.Thread(target=get_url, args = (q,u))
t.daemon = True
t.start()

s = q.get()

print s
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Could you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: access token for facebook expires every one hour so I have to manually fetch the access token within this URL. I would like to do is to create a script where I could go to this URL to fetch the access token. I just edited the post and added a photo so it would be clearer. Hope it helps you! Thank you.

Comment: you can´t renew the token without user interaction, that wold make the whole point of short living tokens void.

Comment: so there's no way for me to renew & fetch new access token automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Two things that aren't clear to me

1. Why you don't exchange the shot-lived token to a long-lived on

As outlined in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending you can exchange the short-lived token to a long-lived one which is valid for 60 days. Short-lived ones are only valid for 2 hours.

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

Depending on what you want to do with the access token, you could also use either an app or a (eternal) page access token. Both of them don't expire, so your problem would be resolved.

2. What this whole thing has to do with threading.

Answer (score -1):

You Can, You can fetch a long live token from a short token which is around 2 months of age!

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.